Why were Poincare, Kronecker and Brouwer hesitant to accept classical logic in an infinite domain but not a finite one?
I am not very well versed in mathematical logic, but I was reading a post on the subject of classical logic and these names popped up.
My guess would be that in theory if we have a finite set of mathematical objects, then we can compute universal statements about them, hence we can check the validity of every first order mathematical statement.
As a consequence of this, classical logic is perfectly valid, as it can be shown that every statement is either true or false.
But in an infinite domain, we no longer have the ability to compute over universal statements.
I may be talking absolute gibberish so please close my question if that is the case.
Thank you.

......[hsm.se]?

Yes, every statement regardin a finite collection of e.g. numbers is obviousli checkable, i.e. decidano.

... unless you care about (something resembling) the actual tractability of exhaustively checking every possibility, in which case there are large (but really not that large) finite numbers that will evade all checking efforts. This would probably lead you to some kind of intuitionistic ultrafinitism (even though a lot of ultrafinitists seem to use classical logic).

Why do you think that those mathematicians really had this attitude ? Without having much historical background , this would surprise me !
